# Data.table fread position error

Tags: r, data.table

Here's an odd behavior for the data.table fread() method, after updating 1.8.1>1.9.2.

```
a.txt:
    "id";"Timestamp"
    "1";"2013-10-19,01:42:11"
```

This doesn't work:

```
> a <- fread("a.txt")
Error in fread("a.txt") : 
  Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=';'
```

Okay, so I've simplified the example this much, and I still can't figure out where my bug is!

Unescaping the id fixes it:

```
1;"2013-10-19,01:42:11"
```

Removing the id fixes it:

```
"2013-10-19,01:42:11"
```

Keeping the id escaped, and simplifying the timestamp fixes it:

```
"1", "2013-10-19"
```

So, why does this error occur? I'm stumped.

Comment: For the immediate future, I just removed the ids, which weren't necessary, but a fix that I don't understand is just a band-aid.

Comment: related: http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5413&group_id=240&atid=975

Comment: With this example, it seems like specifying `sep = ";"` also "fixes" it...

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate even though it came first because this one didn't have an answer, and you can't mark a question as a duplicate of a question that doesn't have an answer.

Comment: As a side note, don't take it personally that the other question got so many upvotes and yours didn't.  I don't see any reason that that question is "better" -- voting on SO just doesn't make sense sometimes.